# Prolog project. Labyrinth. Checking if next move is possible

Tags: prolog

Noob at prolog.
I need to do a school project related to a labyrinth.
My question is:

In the project I need to make a function "possible moves".
It gets a labyrinth, a current position and previous moves

Lab is represented by (these are the walls positions):

```
[[[down,left,up],[left,down,up],[right,up],[up],[,up],[right,left,up]],
[[left,down],[down,up],[down,up],[],[down],[right,down]],
[[left,up],[down,up],[down,up],[down],[down,up],[right,down,up]],
[[right,left],[left,up],[up],[up],[up],[right,up]],
[[left,down],[right,down],[left,down],[down],[down],[right,down]]]
```

And Poss_moves like:

```
Poss_moves(Lab, current_poss, previous_moves, possible_moves)
```

which is called as follows.

```
?- ..., poss_moves(Lab1, (2,5),
[(beginning, 1, 6), (down, 2, 6), (left, 2, 5)], possible_moves).
Lab1 = ...,
Poss = [ (up, 1, 5), (left, 2, 4)].
```

Important:

--- You can only move up, down, left or right.

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

PS: Edited.

PS: Can I do in prolog:

```
distance((Line1, Column1), (Line2, Column2), Dist) :-
    Dist is abs(Line1 - Line2) + abs(Column1 - Column2).
```

PS: The lab that matches the picture.

```
[[[right,left,up],[left,down,up],[down,up],[up],[right,up],[right,left,up]],
[[left,down],[down,up],[b,up],[],[down],[right,down]],
[[left,up],[down,up],[down,up],[down],[down,up],[right,down,up]],
[[right,left],[left,up],[up],[up],[up],[right,up]],
[[left,down],[right,down],[left,down],[down],[down],[right,down]]]
```

By the way, the lab can change.

Thanks

EDIT 2:

I made this changes:

% predicates

```
lookup(Lab,(X,Y),Walls)
calc(Direction,(X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)
map_calc((X,Y),L,R)
poss_moves(Lab, (X,Y), PreviousMoves, PossibleMoves)
```

% clauses

```
nth(1, [H|T], H).
nth(N,[_|T],R) :- 
    M is N-1,
    nth(M,T,R).

lookup(Lab, (X, Y), Walls) :-
    nth(N,Lab,R),
    Y == R,
    X == Walls. 

calc(up,(X,Y1),(X,Y2)) :- 
    Y2 is Y1-1.
calc(down,(X,Y1),(X,Y2)) :- 
    Y2 is Y1+1.
calc(left,(X,Y1),(X,Y2)) :- 
    X2 is X1-1. 
calc(right,(X,Y1),(X,Y2)) :- 
    X2 is X1+1.

map_calc(_,[],[]).
map_calc((X,Y),[H|T],[(H,X1,Y1)|S]) :- 
    calc(H,(X,Y),(X1,Y1)),
    map_calc((X,Y),T,S).
```

% main predicates

```
poss_moves(Lab, (X,Y), PreviousMoves, PossibleMoves) :- 
    lookup(Lab, (X,Y), Walls),
    map_calc((X,Y), Lab, PossibleMoves).
```

I'm almost 100% sure that the lookup is incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: More information needed....Lab1 presumably contains a term describing the whole labyrinth. Please include an example of how this is represented and explain in words what it means. I assume the letters i,b,e,c refer to direction moved? If this is the case then please edit your question to use the words up,down,left or right in your example so its clear. Finally, its better Prolog style to describe your predicate using variables - i.e. CurrentPos instead of current_pos.

Comment: Thanks. Already edited. By the way, beginning means the origin, so it's a previous position. In my project they use poss_moves. Do I change it to possmoves?

Comment: Given Lab = [[[down,left,up],[left,down,up],... does this mean that at co-ordinate (0,0) there are walls preventing you moving down,left and up. And a co-ordinate (1,0) there are walls preventing you moving left,down and up?

Comment: This means that down left up are the position of the walls. Imagine that it's a maze where the first cube is limited by up, left and down by walls, meaning that there is a opening right. That lab is this one: http://imgur.com/cS2u5BT

Comment: the picture above corresponds to the lab: [[[right,left,up],[left,down,up],[down,up],[up],[right,up],[right,left,up]],... if not mistaken.

Comment: Made some changes to my code, if you could tell me if it's right or wrong, I appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is define a way of looking up a cell in the Labryinth datastructure. You need something like:

```
lookup(Lab,(X,Y),Walls)
```

which is true if Walls is the list of walls present at cell (X,Y) in Lab. To do this you'll need an 'nth' predicate which finds the nth element of the list.

```
nth(1,[H|T],H).
nth(N,[_|T],R) :- M is N-1, nth(M,T,R).
```

Normally one would use 0 to return the first element of a list but your maze co-ordinates start at (1,1) so I've made nth do the same.

Now you can build lookup(Lab,(X,Y),Walls) which is true if the Yth element of Lab is Row and the Xth element of Row is Walls.

Next you need a way of turning the list of Walls in to a list of possible moves. A move consists of a direction and the co-ordinates of the new position so first write some helpers to calculate the new co-ordinates:

```
calc(Direction,(X1,Y1),(X2,Y2)
```

should be true if (X2,Y2) is the co-ordinate you get to if you move in Direction from (X1,Y1).  Here is an example clause of calc, the others are similar:

```
calc(up,(X,Y1),(X,Y2)) :- Y2 is Y1-1.
```

But we need to apply calc to every element of the list of Walls to get the list of moves (this is called 'map' in functional programming)

```
map_calc((X,Y),L,R)
```

should be true if R is the result of applying calc to every direction in L starting from co-ordinate (X,Y).

```
map_calc(_,[],[]).
map_calc((X,Y),[H|T],[(H,X1,Y1)|S]) :- calc(H,(X,Y),(X1,Y1)),
                                       map_calc((X,Y),T,S).
```

Now you can write poss_moves:

```
poss_moves(Lab, (X,Y), PreviousMoves, PossibleMoves)
```

i.e. PossibleMoves is the list of moves you can make from (X,Y) given that lookup(Lab,(X,Y),Walls) is true, and that map_calc on Walls gives you PossibleMoves.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will do that and I will tell you if it worked. By the way, how can I call a predicate from a predicate (sort possiblemoves by distance). It's the next predicate but now I will work on this one first. Thanks

Comment: Please ask that as a new question since its unrelated to your question here.

Comment: Made some changes to my code, if you could tell me if it's right or wrong, I appreciate.

Comment: Please don't change your question further. You now have a new question about implementing a lookup predicate (which is independent from your labyrinth question) so please ask it as a new question.

Comment: It's not independent. I was just asking if this was the correct way of solving the PossibleMoves. If it wasn't then I would ask how to do a lookup predicate.

Comment: How can I filter my possiblemoves from previousmoves. Last thing I need.